# Generation of PDF file with XeLatex

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, xelatex

I installed TexMaker, MikTex and a font package.
I try to run a code on TexMaker, which tells me to compile with XeLatex because of the packages used.
When I run with XeLatex, there don't seem to be mistake, but no PDF is generated. I can't understand why.
[image: Here is the sceenshot after compiling]

And following is the backlog.
Do you know why I can't generate PDF file?
Thanks for answers

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.12) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.3.9)  9 MAR 2022 22:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./cv.tex
(cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/marvosym\marvosym.sty
Package: marvosym 2011/07/20 v2.2 Martin Vogel's Symbols font definitions
) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.st
y
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xpar
se.sty
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xe
tex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-10-18 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count187
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count188
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count189
\g__graphics_track_int=\count190
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count192
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count193
))
Package: xparse 2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xete
x.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141
 (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)
))
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/xelatex/xunicode\xunicode.st
y
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane
 (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tipa\t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
)
\tipaTiiicode=\count271
\tipasavetokens=\toks16
\tipachecktokens=\toks17

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.
cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2021/03/18 v5.0k Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/parskip\parskip.sty
Package: parskip 2021-03-14 v2.0h non-zero parskip adjustments

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.st
y
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.
sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count272
)) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\color.sty
Package: color 2021/10/11 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 149.
) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Package option `usenames' ignored on input line 218.
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 227.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \color on input line 711.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/layaureo\layaureo.sty
Package: layaureo 2004/09/16 v0.2

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count273
\Gm@cntv=\count274
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count275
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen144
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen146
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen148
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen149
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen151
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg)
) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count276
\calc@Bcount=\count277
\calc@Adimen=\dimen152
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen153
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count278
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
\LA@MargineRilegatura=\skip52
\LA@LarghezzaTesto=\skip53
\LA@AltezzaTesto=\skip54
\LA@MargineSinistro=\skip55
\LA@MargineSuperiore=\skip56
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/supertabular\supertabu
lar.sty
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count279
\ST@wd=\dimen154
\ST@rightskip=\skip57
\ST@leftskip=\skip58
\ST@parfillskip=\skip59
\ST@pageleft=\dimen155
\ST@headht=\dimen156
\ST@tailht=\dimen157
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen158
\ST@pboxht=\dimen159
\ST@lineht=\dimen160
\ST@prevht=\dimen161
\ST@toadd=\dimen162
\ST@dimen=\dimen163
\ST@pbox=\box51
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/titlesec\titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2021/07/05 v2.14 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box52
\beforetitleunit=\skip60
\aftertitleunit=\skip61
\ttl@plus=\dimen164
\ttl@minus=\dimen165
\ttl@toksa=\toks20
\titlewidth=\dimen166
\titlewidthlast=\dimen167
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen168
) (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.st
y
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmd
s.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.
sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefin
ekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.
sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacr
o.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen169
\Hy@linkcounter=\count280
\Hy@pagecounter=\count281

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-lang
patches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.st
y
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count282
 (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc-greekba
sic.def
File: puenc-greekbasic.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (
greek block) (HO)
))
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count283
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen170

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcal
c.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count284
\Field@Width=\dimen171
\Fld@charsize=\dimen172
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on
```